# Django haystack including related content and also boosting it

Tags: django, django-haystack

I'm playing with django-haystack and trying to implement it with elasticsearch (I already did actually). My model has `title`, `content` and also a `tags` field which is a `ManyRelatedManager`:

`tags = models.ManyToManyField( 'Tag', through = 'PostTags' )`

My search index object is built as follows:

```
class PostIndex( indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable ):
    text = indexes.CharField( document = True, use_template = True )
    title = indexes.CharField( model_attr = 'title', boost = 1.125 )
    content = indexes.CharField( model_attr = 'content' )
    date_added = indexes.DateTimeField( model_attr = 'date_added' )
```

My first question is...how do I include the tags in the `PostIndex` object? I want to give the tags a much higher boost compared to the title and content.

`post_text.txt` template:

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.content }}
{% for tag in object.tags.all %}
    {{ tag.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a multi facet field for the tags and populate & boost that at indexing time.
In your PostIndex model:

```
tags = FacetMultiValueField(boost = 2)
```

and

```
def prepare_tags(self, obj):
    return [t.name for t in obj.tags.all()]
```

Comment: I still don't get a boost unfortunately.